# How do you setup an Azure Pipeline such that it automatically updates and build after you push to github?

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I configured an azure pipeline with these sets:

1. Create organization `organization`
2. Create project `project`
3. Go to repository tab and import my repository from my github account
4. Click "build" and point azure at the azure-pipelines.yml file containing the build information.

What I want to happen is when I push to my github repository, github automatically pushes to azure to start the build. However this doesn't happen.

I have tried to associate my github account with my azure account by going to `Settings > Boards > github connections`, but this does not resolve my problem.

How do you setup an Azure Pipeline such that it automatically updates and build after you push to github?

Comment: Are you trying to mirror source to Azure DevOps, or simply build source stored in GitHub from Azure DevOps? You don't need to mirror the source code to build from GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the `yml` build definition, you can configure your Pipeline to build and release continuously with CI/CD triggers.

[Continuous integration (CI) triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) cause a pipeline to run whenever you push an update to the specified branches or you push specified tags.

You can control which branches get CI triggers with a simple syntax:

```
trigger:
- master
- releases/*
```

Next, [Continuous deployment (CD) triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops) allow you to create a release every time a new build artifact is available.

[image: CD Trigger]

Here are some resources that explain these steps in greater detail:

- Azure DevOps Labs: [GitHub integration with Azure Pipelines](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/github-azurepipelines/)
- [Azure DevOps YAML release pipeline](https://dev.to/kenakamu/azure-devops-yaml-release-pipeline-trigger-when-build-pipeline-completed-54d5)